# Codeigniter - Oracle - Trying to get property of non-object (foreach)

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, foreach

I got error message while trying to display data from oracle database with codeigniter :

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: pages/v_soaotc_daily.php

This is my **MODEL** :

```
public function get_CollProd(){
    $this->pblmig_db = $this->load->database('collprod', true);

    $sql="select * from inh_soa_otc_control where module_name = 'Daily_Recurring_Grabber'";

    $stmt = oci_parse($this->pblmig_db->conn_id, $sql);

    oci_execute($stmt);
    $row = oci_fetch_all($stmt, $result);
    oci_free_statement($stmt);
    oci_close($this->pblmig_db->conn_id);
    return $result;
}
```

**CONTROLLER** :

```
function daily(){
        $data=array(
            'title'=>'SOA_OTC - Daily',
            'active_otc'=>'active',
            'dtl'=>$this->model_app->get_CollProd()
        );

        $this->load->view('element/v_header',$data);
        $this->load->view('pages/v_soaotc_daily');
        $this->load->view('element/v_footer');
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
if(isset($dtl)){

foreach($dtl as $row){
?>
<tr>
   <td><?php echo $row->sum_amount; ?></td>
</tr>
```

And this is the **print_r($dtl)** array result :

```
Array
(
    [MODULE_NAME] => Array
        (
            [0] => Daily_Recurring_Grabber
            [1] => Daily_Recurring_Grabber           
        )
    [START_EXECUTION] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19-SEP-14
            [1] => 21-SEP-14           
        )
    [FINISHED_EXECUTION] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19-SEP-14
            [1] => 21-SEP-14          
        )
    [NUM_OF_POPULATION] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6630
            [1] => 6169
        )
     [SUM_AMOUNT] => Array
        (
            [0] => 397922098.33
            [1] => 360955418.47
        )
)
```

I just wanted to do simple foreach to display SUM_AMOUNT field. But I get that error message.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: its array and not object so `$row['sum_amount']` will work and `$row->sum_amount` will not. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with -

```
<td><?php echo $row['SUM_AMOUNT']; ?></td>
```

But `SUM_AMOUNT` is an array itself so you should have another foreach.

Comment: Thanks for help, yes, now i get an error message : Undefined index. I'm quite sure it caused by there is no foreach for sum_amount as you said. But how to do that? Would you help me to give the code snippet for this one?

Comment: how do you want this??